# How to access the Wikidata SPARQL interface from Java?

Tags: java, sparql, wikidata, sesame

I am trying to query all instances of an entity from Wikidata. I found out that currently the only way to do this is to use the SPARQL endpoint.

I found an example query which does about what I want to do and successfully executed it from the Web interface. Unfortunately I can't seem to be able to execute it from within my Java code. I am using the openRDF SPARQL library. Here is my relevant code:

```
SPARQLRepository sparqlRepository = new SPARQLRepository(
        "https://query.wikidata.org/");
SPARQLConnection sparqlConnection = new SPARQLConnection(
        sparqlRepository);

String query = "SELECT ?s ?desc ?authorlabel (COUNT(DISTINCT ?sitelink) as ?linkcount) WHERE {"
        + "?s wdt:P31 wd:Q571 ."
        + "?sitelink schema:about ?s ."
        + "?s wdt:P50 ?author"
        + "OPTIONAL { ?s rdfs:label ?desc filter (lang(?desc) = \"en\"). }"
        + "OPTIONAL {"
        + "?author rdfs:label ?authorlabel filter (lang(?authorlabel) = \"en\")."
        + "}"
        + "} GROUP BY ?s ?desc ?authorlabel ORDER BY DESC(?linkcount)";

TupleQuery tupleQuery = sparqlConnection.prepareTupleQuery(
        QueryLanguage.SPARQL, query);
System.out.println("Result for tupleQuery" + tupleQuery.evaluate());
```

And here is the response I'm receiving:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openrdf.query.QueryEvaluationException: <html>
<head><title>405 Not Allowed</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>405 Not Allowed</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.9.4</center>
</body>
</html>
    at org.openrdf.repository.sparql.query.SPARQLTupleQuery.evaluate(SPARQLTupleQuery.java:59)
    at main.Test.main(Test.java:72)
Caused by: org.openrdf.repository.RepositoryException: <html>
<head><title>405 Not Allowed</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>405 Not Allowed</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.9.4</center>
</body>
</html>
    at org.openrdf.http.client.HTTPClient.handleHTTPError(HTTPClient.java:953)
    at org.openrdf.http.client.HTTPClient.sendTupleQueryViaHttp(HTTPClient.java:718)
    at org.openrdf.http.client.HTTPClient.getBackgroundTupleQueryResult(HTTPClient.java:602)
    at org.openrdf.http.client.HTTPClient.sendTupleQuery(HTTPClient.java:367)
    at org.openrdf.repository.sparql.query.SPARQLTupleQuery.evaluate(SPARQLTupleQuery.java:52)
    ... 1 more
```

Normally I would assume that this means I need an API key of sorts, but the Wikidata API appears to be completely open. Did I make a mistake setting up my connection?

Comment: Also see [Use Jena to query wikidata](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36535702/use-jena-to-query-wikidata).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The proper endpoint URL for Wikidata is `https://query.wikidata.org/sparql` - you're missing the last bit.

In addition, I noticed a few glitches in your code. First of all, you're doing this:

```
SPARQLConnection sparqlConnection = new SPARQLConnection(sparqlRepository);
```

This should be this:

```
RepositoryConnection sparqlConnection = sparqlRepository.getConnection();
```

Always retrieve your connection object from the `Repository` object using `getConnection()` - this means resources are shared and the `Repository` can close 'dangling' connections if necessary.

Secondly: you can't print out the result of a query like this:

```
System.out.println("Result for tupleQuery" + tupleQuery.evaluate());
```

If you wish to print out the result to `System.out` you should instead do something like this:

```
tupleQuery.evaluate(new SPARQLResultsTSVWriter(System.out));
```

Or (if you wish to customize the result a bit more):

```
for (BindingSet bs : QueryResults.asList(tupleQuery.evaluate())) {
    System.out.println(bs);
}
```

For what it's worth - with the above changes the query request runs, but it appears your query is too 'heavy' for Wikidata - at least I got a timeout error from the server. Try a simpler query though, and you'll see the code works.

Comment: Thank you for these useful hints. I used Sysout as a test, it shouĺd call the toString() method of tupleQuery.evaluate() which is enough to see if it works at all.

Answer (score 4):

When I go to https://query.wikidata.org/ and have a look at Tools > SPARQL REST endpoint, I see (emphasis added):

> #### SPARQL endpoint
>
> SPARQL queries can be submitted directly to the SPARQL endpoint with a GET request to **https://query.wikidata.org/sparql?query={SPARQL}** (POST and other method requests will be denied with a "403 Forbidden").* The result is returned as XML by default, or as JSON if either the query parameter format=json or the header Accept: application/sparql-results+json are provided.

It looks like you're using a different URL (it doesn't look like you have the final `sparql` on there), so you're probably not actually hitting that endpoint.

That said, since you can visit the URL that you *are* using (presumably using GET), it sounds like your API call might be doing a POST, so you may want to check how the query is going over the network, too.

There's an example of using this endpoint from Jena in [Use Jena to query wikidata](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36535702/use-jena-to-query-wikidata).  The OP of that question actually had the same issue you're running into (the wrong query URL).